# promblem while trying to define two numbers in c# programe for average stock calculator

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2019, average

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace average_stock_calculator
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            decimal  a, b, c, d, sum, average;
         

            Console.WriteLine("First purchase price:");
         
            a = Convert.ToDecimal(Console.ReadLine());
            
            Console.WriteLine("Second purchase price:");
            b = Convert.ToDecimal(Console.ReadLine());

            Console.WriteLine("Third purchase price:");
            c = Convert.ToDecimal(Console.ReadLine());

            Console.WriteLine("Fouth purchase price:");
            d = Convert.ToDecimal(Console.ReadLine());

            //Processing
            sum = a + b + c + d;
            average = sum/4;
            
            Console.WriteLine("Average buying price={0}", average);

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

note: i want to add first purchase quntity and first purchase price together, i have no idea how to do it! can someone help?
it should look like this,
enter first purchase quntity & price
and i shuold be able to enter quntity 10 and price 20 together, and then at the end i should get the average buy quantity and price together.

Comment: Why would you *add* a quantity and a price? They'd have different units. Normally you'd *multiply* them together. If I have 5 things each costing $2, that's a cost of $10, not 7...

Comment: Additionally, your code doesn't currently ask for quantities at all... only prices.

Comment: am trying to create an application on which people can find out the average of stocks they bought on different dates also in different quantity and at different price.

Comment: None of that addresses anything in my comments though.

Comment: Are you trying to have an input, on the same line, for both quantity and price and then separate the input to different counters?

Comment: yes steve, youre right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a simple modification for you.

Codes:

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApp9
{
    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Purchase a, b, c, d;
            Console.WriteLine("First purchase price and amount:");
            a = ReadL();
            Console.WriteLine("Second purchase price and amount:");
            b = ReadL();
            Console.WriteLine("Third purchase price and amount:");
            c = ReadL();
            Console.WriteLine("Fouth purchase price: and amount:");
            d = ReadL();

            //Processing
            Purchase Sum = new Purchase();
            Sum.price = a.price + b.price + c.price + d.price;
            Sum.amount = a.amount + b.amount + c.amount + d.amount;

            Purchase Average = new Purchase();
            Average.price = Sum.price / 4;
            Average.amount = Sum.amount / 4;

            Console.WriteLine("Average buying price={0},Average buying amount={1}", Average.price, Average.amount);

            Console.ReadKey();

            Purchase ReadL()
            {
                Purchase X = new Purchase();
                var inputs = Console.ReadLine().Split(' ');
                X.amount = Convert.ToDecimal(inputs[0]);
                X.price = Convert.ToDecimal(inputs[1]);
                return X;
            }
        }
        class Purchase
        {
            public decimal price { get; set; }
            public decimal amount { get; set; }
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

[image]